# Woods 59104R pro timer issue

Tags: electrical, wiring, pool, timer

I installed a Woods 59104R pro timer on my pool pump. It works partially and can shut down the pool pump at the specified time, but it also shuts itself down at that time. The clock stops rotating and of course, doesn't start back up by itself. I thought I followed the wiring instruction correctly, but I guess I missed something or as one user on amazon mentioned, his electrician had to adjust the contacts manually, whatever that means. I have attached a picture of my wiring, along with the wiring diagram that I used. The red wire is a jumper wire between the neutral port and the 3rd port. Any idea what could be wrong?

[image: Timer wiring]

Comment: Those bare copper earth wires would have green/yellow sleeving where I am from - makes things less likely to touch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if this is a 240V device, ALL those white wires (on both ends) must be marked with black tape to indicate they are actually hots.

The crux of your problem is you confused supply side with the load side.  Perhaps you assumed "this is a switch, doesn't matter on switches".  Yes, but it also needs power to run itself.

What's universally useful anytime you are dealing with a Line and Load side, is to not hook up LOAD until you have LINE hooked up and everything working with the device/timer/GFCI/whatever.

So figure out which side actually does go to the pool pump, unhook it, and cap it off.  Leave it unhooked.  Now wire up the unit so it behaves normally - is able to cycle on/off, keeps running normally, etc.

This will expose all possible errors - confusing Line and Load, connecting the timer drive to the wrong wire, etc.   It will force you to "get it right" and you won't be able to continue until you do.

Once the timer is sympatico, then finally hook up your Load.

Comment: I would use a multimeter to see which terminals go live when the device switches, rotating by hand to check.

Comment: Typical "I'm an idiot" kinda thing. I wired it as the diagram and the youtube video showed, but forgot that MY source of power was on the right and not the left. So, as Harper - Reinstate Monica said, I confused line and load.